# How to change the variable in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this below function.

```
def replace_zeros(nums1):
    for n in nums1:
        print 'nums1=', nums1, 'n=', n
        if n == 0:
            nums1[nums1.index(n)] = 2
    return nums1

print replace_zeros([1,2,3,0,0,0])
```

which was giving me the following output

```
>>> print replace_zeros([1,2,3,0,0,0])
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 1
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 2
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 3
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 0
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0] n= 0
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0] n= 0
```

I am getting 'n' from nums1 only but why 'n' value is not changing even 'nums1' is changed?
Could you let know how to change 'nums1' with changing value?

Consider this below python function

```
def replace_zeros(nums1):
    for n in nums1:
        nums1.insert(1, 2)
        nums1 = nums1[:-1]
        print 'nums1=', nums1, 'n=', n
        if n == 0:
           nums1[nums1.index(n)] = 2
return nums1

print replace_zeros([1,2,3,0,0,0])
```

I am getting index error at "nums1[nums1.index(n)] = 2", why still I am getting index error even if I check n==0? i.e.even though nums1 is changing inside loop, the 'n' value that we first retrieved from 'for' loop did not change. I want that 'n' to be changed along with nums1.

I am looking for something like reloading nums1 so that 'n' will change and 'n==0' condition should become False to do not enter that 'if' block so that no index error raises.

I know that what 'n' should contain will be defined when we do 'for n in nums1', but I want that 'n' to be dynamically changed with changing 'nums1' inside for loop.

Comment: I can’t see anything wrong. It looks like you are getting what you want.

Comment: What exactly is the output you were expecting?

Comment: On a side note - using `index` here is rather inefficient... at some point when you get around to using them - a list comprehension is what you want here... eg: `nums1[:] = [2 if n == 0 else n for n in nums]` will do what the function above does...

Comment: automatically changing 'n'. Even nums1 is changing to [1,2,3,2,0,0], n is still 1,2,3,0,0,0

Comment: I see. That doesn't happen in your code since you print before changing the value in the array and also updating the value in the array does not mean that the variable `n` is updated. You'd have to do that explicitly if you want that, see @Sheri's answer below.

Comment: `n` points to the object representing the value at the current point in the iteration - which is 0 since you haven't replaced that value yet. After replacing, n still points to that object, but that object no longer happens to be in the list

Comment: When using a `for` loop on a list like that, `n` is actually iterating on an **iterator** of the list created for the loop. So even if you are changing the list in the middle of the loop, you will not see these changes in `n` because its values are already determined at the start of the loop. Even if you try to manually change it, in the next iteration it will go back to its designated next value

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the print statements, I recommend a list comprehension for the replace function:

```py
def replace_zeros(arr):
    return [n if n != 0 else 2 for n in arr]
```

Comment: Or simply `[n or 2 for n in arr]`

Comment: Assuming there will only be numbers in the array, yes, that'd be even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are replacing `0` with `2` but you are not changing the value of `n` inside `if` statement where you are replacing zeros

```
def replace_zeros(nums1):
    for n in nums1:
        if n == 0:
            nums1[nums1.index(n)] = 2
            n = 2
        print('nums1=', nums1, 'n=', n)
    return nums1

print(replace_zeros([1,2,3,0,0,0]))
```

Output:

```
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 1                                                                                        
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 2                                                                                        
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] n= 3                                                                                        
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0] n= 2                                                                                        
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0] n= 2                                                                                        
nums1= [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2] n= 2                                                                                        
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to use an enumeration:

```
def replace_zeros(nums1):
    for index,n in enumerate(nums1):
        if n == 0:
            nums1[index] = 2
        print('nums1=', nums1, 'n=', n)
    return nums1
```